# Removing a duplicate row from source spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

MASTER-PRE contains the master data,
PRE pulls data from the master data using IMPORTRANGE.
IMPORTRANGE is columns B-N from MASTER-PRE.
When a value is entered in column O on PRE, the below code is run and it drops the row back into MASTER-PRE.
However, it is a duplicate just with the value of column O added.

How do I amend the below code to either:
a) overwrite the exiting row
b) delete the duplicate row that doesn't contain a value in column O

```
function run2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRE");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER_PRE");

  // 1. Retrieve the values from "A2:G" of sheet "IN".
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange("B6:O" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an object for putting values and deleting the contents of the columns "E" and "F".
  var obj = srcValues.reduce((o, [B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O], i) => {
    if (O != "") {
      o.values.push([B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O]);
      //o.ranges.push(`E${i + 2}:F${i + 2}`);
    }
    return o;
  }, {values: [], ranges: []});

  // 3. Copy the values to the sheet "ORDERS".
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, obj.values.length, obj.values[0].length).setValues(obj.values);

  // 4. Delete the contents of the columns "E" and "F" of sheet "IN".
  //srcSheet.getRangeList(obj.ranges).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Have you done anything to accomplish the stated goal?

Comment: @TheMaster - There are lots of forum posts regarding the removal of duplicate rows  - it's adapting it work that is the issue. I thought about making a 3rd sheet, where the results of the code could be pushed to, but i'd need a 4th sheet also to merge the results of MASTER_PRE and the 3rd sheet, because yet another sheet takes uses  the merged results.I have no idea whether what i want to achieve is a one line bit of code, or whether it needs a brand new script writing - i'm just throwing it out there for some advice.

Comment: When asking questions, you're expected to know, at the very least, what the code you posted does.  You should have a practical understanding of arrays and it's methods. If not, consider reviewing arrays and it's methods in mdn/other documentation before adding a question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I used the following query/arrayformula in another sheet:

=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(UNIQUE(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(MASTER_PRE!B1:O, "select N where N is not null order by K desc", 0),
 QUERY(MASTER_PRE!B1:O, "select N,K,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,L,M,O where N is not null order by K desc", 0), {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,12,13,1,14}, 0)), 1, 1))

Full credit to @player0 for his answer on this post:
[[Formula to filter unique rows with highest value in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813824/formula-to-filter-unique-rows-with-highest-value-in-google-sheets])