# Can you prioritize which duplicate data to keep given at least one column contains a unique value when cleaning up duplicates in Googlesheets?

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, max, countif

I have a massive list of donor information spanning two years of donations in Googlesheets. The list includes names, contact info, and the donation amount. Many folks have given multiple times over the last two years. I need to reduce the list and plan to delete duplicates, but I need to keep their information pertaining to the highest donation amount. Essentially, looking to create a list with no duplicate contacts that contains the highest donation amount for each contact that they gave. How do I make this happen?

I tried format and conditional formatting, but I don't know how to set the parameter for keeping the row of data with the highest donation value within the set of duplicates.

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: Since your data covers several years, what is your definition of "no duplicates"? Is it based on name alone, or name and address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formula to filter unique rows with highest value in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56813824/formula-to-filter-unique-rows-with-highest-value-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.